# How to replace certain symbols in dtype.names in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, replace, genfromtxt

I have a data file of the form given below:

```
column_1    column 2    column-3    column-4    column_5    column 6
1   2   3   1   2   3
4   3   2   3   2   4
1   4   3   1   4   3
5   6   4   5   6   4
```

When I import the following file the header names with spaces are automatically replaced by underscores which I replace back with spaces. But how to preserve the hyphens. The code I used is:

```
import numpy as np
with open('data.dat', 'rb') as f:
    header = f.readline().split('\t')
    arr = np.genfromtxt(f, names = header, comments='#', delimiter='\t', dtype=None)
arr.dtype.names = [j.replace('_', ' ').replace('-', ' ') for j in arr.dtype.names]
print arr.dtype.names
```

**Output**

```
('column_1', 'column_2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column_5', 'column_6')
```

How to get back the hyphens of column 3 and 4 in Python?

Comment: You can't - how do you know, for a given header, whether the underscore replaces a space or a hyphen?

Comment: You already have the original header stored as `header`... why not use that? Maybe just `arr.dtype.names = header` will do it...

Comment: There are a couple of parameters in `genfromtxt` that affect these names, e.g. `replace_space` and `deletechars`.  Play with those.

Answer (score 0):

Hint - you can use ***regex*** for extracting the data in the columns, for your above case the expression will look similar to this `exp = r'column.\d'`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your headers are separated by `\t` in your file:

```py
import numpy as np
with open('data.dat', 'rb') as f:
    header = f.read().split("\n")[0].split("\t")
    arr = np.genfromtxt(f, names = header,comments='#', delimiter='\t', dtype=object)
arr.dtype.names = [j.replace('_', ' ') if j[:-1]+"-"+j[-1] not in header else j[:-1]+"-"+j[-1] for j in arr.dtype.names]
print arr.dtype.names

>> ('column 1', 'column 2', 'column-3', 'column-4', 'column 5', 'column 6')
```